# Different results in DFT and FFT (python)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, dft

I'm using FFT to perform some transformations in my PhD thesis. Since I need the Fourier transform to be in certain frequencies, I thought of programming my own DFT (I cannot use FFT since its frequencies are fixed by sample number and rate).

But I encounter differences between the output of both algorithms.

**Here is a minimal example**, which reproduces DFT and FFT calculations and outputs some comparative figures:

```
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift, fftfreq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setting gaussian signal to perform example
N = 200 #sample number
x = np.linspace (-100,100,N) #axis to perform fft into
delta = x[1]-x[0] #space between samples
sigma = 10 #numerical value
freqs = fftshift(fftfreq(N, d=delta)) #FFT output frequencies. Will also be used in DFT to contrast results

#Calculating signal
signal = np.exp(-x**2/sigma**2)

#Plot input signal, for reference
plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.title("Input signal")
plt.show()

#Perform fft
output_fft = fftshift(fft(signal))

#Perform DFT in same frequencies as FFT
output_DFT1 = []
for fx in freqs:
    spec = np.sum(signal * np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi * fx * x))
    output_DFT1.append(spec)

#Plotting comparative results

#Real part 
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(freqs, np.real(output_fft), label='FFT')
plt.plot(freqs, np.real(output_DFT1), label='DFT1')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title("Comparative on FFT and DFT real parts")
plt.show()

#Imaginary part
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(output_fft), label='FFT')
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(output_DFT1), label='DFT1')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title("Comparative on FFT and DFT imag parts")
plt.show()
```

here are my output images:
[Real part comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYChd.png)
[Imaginary part comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/953Zb.png)

**Why are the results different?**

Answer (score 0):

I have followed Eq.1 in [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) about DFT and the result is similar with both methods in scipy; fft and dft. Here is the code:

```py
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift, fftfreq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setting gaussian signal to perform example
N = 200 #sample number
x = np.linspace (-100,100,N) #axis to perform fft into
delta = x[1]-x[0] #space between samples
sigma = 10 #numerical value
freqs = fftshift(fftfreq(N, d=delta)) #FFT output frequencies. Will also be used in DFT to contrast results
freqs_no_shift = fftfreq(N, d=delta)

#Calculating signal
signal = np.exp(-x**2/sigma**2)

#Plot input signal, for reference
plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.title("Input signal")
plt.show()

#Perform fft
output_fft = fftshift(fft(signal))

#Perform DFT in same frequencies as FFT
output_DFT1 = []
for idx, fx in enumerate(freqs_no_shift):
    spec = 0
    for i, ampi in enumerate(signal):
        spec += ampi * np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*idx*i/len(signal))
    output_DFT1.append(spec)
output_DFT1 = fftshift(np.array(output_DFT1))

from scipy.linalg import dft
m = dft(len(signal))
dft2 = m @ signal
dft2 = fftshift(dft2)

#Plotting comparative results

#Real part 
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(freqs, np.real(output_fft), label='FFT')
plt.plot(freqs, np.real(output_DFT1), label='DFT1')
plt.plot(freqs, np.real(dft2), label='DFT2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title("Comparative on FFT and DFT real parts")
plt.show()

#Imaginary part
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(output_fft), label='FFT')
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(output_DFT1), label='DFT1')
plt.plot(freqs, np.imag(dft2), label='DFT2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title("Comparative on FFT and DFT imag parts")
plt.show()
```

Hopefully, it helps your problem.